# Why i have this issue with cv2.findContours function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/michail.gakas/Desktop/python scripts/counters.1py.py", line 10, in 
>       imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>   error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('star.jpg',0)

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am using python 2.7 CV3 but i had CV2 installed before

Comment: either load as COLOR image and convert to grayscale or load as grayscale and dont try to convert from color to gray

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michail.gakas\Desktop\python scripts\counters.1py.py", line 12, in <module>
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2494: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

Answer (score 1):

I don't have OpenCV with me right now but from what I see you did

```
img = cv2.imread("star.jpg", 0)
```

but what you probably wanted to do is open it in color as:

```
img = cv2.imread("star.jpg", 1)
```

or open it "unchanged" as:

```
img = cv2.imread("star.jpg", -1)
```

What you did is you opened an image in grayscale mode and then tried to convert it to grayscale. That error actually states that `assert` didn't find an image with 3 or 4 channels and `BGR2GRAYSCALE` goes from a color jpg image (3 channels) or a color png image (4 channels, 1 for alpha sometimes) to a 1 channel grayscale image. Alpha channel is discarded in this function. Pls make your life easier and use the official flags cv2 offers for easier code readability.

```
cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED (<0) loads the image as is (including the alpha channel if present)
cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE ( 0) loads the image as an intensity one
cv2.IMREAD_COLOR (>0) loads the image in the RGB format
```